# numpy split doesn't work on float array

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to split a float array into sub arrays using numpy split, however the results are not correct:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.5])
np.split(x, [1, 2, 3])

Out[127]: [array([ 1.2]), array([ 1.3]), array([ 1.5]), array([ 2. ,  2.1,  2.5])]
```

1.2, 1.3 and 1.5 should be put into one sub array but they are separated, whereas it seems it splits the 2, 2.1 and 2.5 correctly.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)?  Pretty sure split doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: If you expect `[array([1.2, 1.3, 1.5]), array([2., 2.1, 2.5])` then `np.split(x, [3])` should give you what you want.

Comment: The second example in the documentation split np.arange(8.0) into 5 subarrays using [3, 5, 6, 10] as splitting sections. The 5 subarrays are array([ 0.,  1.,  2.]), array([ 3.,  4.]), array([ 5.]), array([ 6.,  7.]) and array([], dtype=float64)]

Comment: @Xiangyu: You're misinterpreting the results. It's splitting at indices, not values. Since the values and indices are equal in this particular array, it sort of looks like it's splitting on values, but it's not. You have to read the part of the documentation where it explains what the function does, not just look at the examples and try to extrapolate.

Comment: @user2357112, thank you for the answer. Yea, I thought it was splitting at values.

Comment: @BrenBarn I was confused by the documentation and thought it was splitting at values. Now I know it splits at indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to split the array into the elements that are smaller than 1, between 1 and 2, between 2 and 3 and greater than 3 (4 bins). If we assume the array is sorted then the following will work:

```
>>> x = np.array([0.4, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.5, 3.4])
>>> np.split(x, np.bincount(np.digitize(x, [1, 2, 3])).cumsum())[:-1]
[array([ 0.4]),
 array([ 1.2,  1.3,  1.5]),
 array([ 2. ,  2.1,  2.5]),
 array([ 3.4])]
```

With `np.digitize` we get the index of the bin for each array element.  With `np.bincount` we get the number of elements in each bin. With `np.cumsum` we can take the splitting indexes of each bin in the sorted array. Finally, we have what `np.split` needs.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: does this work if the np.digitize is with float values? I wanna see if values are between 0.23 and 0.56. ```array([ 0.2109375 ,  0.46835897,  0.72578044,  0.98320192,  1.24062339,
        1.49804486,  1.75546633,  2.0128878 ,  2.27030928,  2.52773075])```

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

> numpy.split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis=0)
>
> indices_or_sections : int or 1-D array If indices_or_sections is an
>   integer, N, the array will be divided into N equal arrays along axis.
>   If such a split is not possible, an error is raised. If
>   indices_or_sections is a 1-D array of sorted integers, the entries
>   indicate where along axis the array is split. For example, [2, 3]
>   would, for axis=0, result in ary[:2] ary[2:3] ary[3:] If an index
>   exceeds the dimension of the array along axis, an empty sub-array is
>   returned correspondingly.

So, if you want to split a the third element on the axis you need to do something like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.array([1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.5])

In[3]: np.split(x, [3])
Out[3]: [array([ 1.2,  1.3,  1.5]), array([ 2. ,  2.1,  2.5])]
```

If you rather want to split the array `x` into two equal sub-arrays:

```
In [4]: np.split(x, 2)
Out[4]: [array([ 1.2,  1.3,  1.5]), array([ 2. ,  2.1,  2.5])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to first generate bins and then put the elements in array x to its corresponding bins. I am confused by the documentation as I thought if I use [1,2,3] it would set up the "bins". Thanks to @user2357112, now I understand it is splitting at indices.

Comment: Splitting on indices or dividing into equal-sized sub-arrays. Depending on what you pass to the function as stated in the docs and showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`np.split(x, [1, 2, 3])` gives you `x[:1], x[1:2], x[3:]` which obviously is not what you want.  It seems what you want is `np.split(x, [3])`.